# Get variables from one public section into another

Tags: c#

probably a very simple noob question here. Basically I have a txt file that has a number of variables that control a service I wrote. Currently in every void that needs a variable from there I have it opening the file, reading the file, picking out the line and then using the variable.

My question is, is there a way to globally assign variables. so that all my voids can use them. That way I only need to open the file once read everything, assign everything a variable. instead of the way I am doing it now where I am opening the file multiple times looking for in most cases the same variable.

I edited my question and added some code to attempt to explain better. 
so below I have 2 voids. they are both opening the same file, but looking for a different line in the file. I am wondering if it's possible to create a "global" variable list that reads the whole file and then I can just call the variables I need instead of opening the file everytime I am needing info out of it.

```
       public void day_timer()
    {
        string temptimer = "";
        string timeloop = "";
        using (var streamReader = System.IO.File.OpenText(@"C:\somefile"))
        {
            var lines = streamReader.ReadToEnd().Split("\r\n".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            foreach (var line in lines)
            {
                if (line.Contains("Day_Time:"))
                {
                    temptimer = line;
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
        timeloop = temptimer.Remove(0, 9);
        int inter = Convert.ToInt32(timeloop);
        System.Timers.Timer timer1 = new System.Timers.Timer();
        InitializeComponent();
        timer1.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer1_Elapsed);
        timer1.Interval = inter * 1000 * 60;
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        timer1.Start();
        error_handling("backup started " + DateTime.Now + ". Incremental Backup set to every " + timeloop + " Minutes", "Incbackuplog.txt");
    }

    //Incrememtal Backup Timer
    public void inc_timer()
    {
        string temptimer = "";
        string timeloop = "";
        using (var streamReader = System.IO.File.OpenText(@"C:\somefile"))
        {
            var lines = streamReader.ReadToEnd().Split("\r\n".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            foreach (var line in lines)
            {
                if (line.Contains("Inc_interval:"))
                {
                    temptimer = line;
                    continue;
                }                
            }
        }
        timeloop = temptimer.Remove(0, 13);
        int inter = Convert.ToInt32(timeloop);
        System.Timers.Timer timer1 = new System.Timers.Timer();
        InitializeComponent();
        timer1.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer1_Elapsed);
        timer1.Interval = inter * 1000 * 60;
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        timer1.Start();
        error_handling(" Backup Started "+DateTime.Now+". Incremental Backup set to every "+timeloop+" Minutes", "Incbackuplog.txt");
    }
```

Comment: There are many ways to do this, hard to recommend a path without some code or more info.

Comment: Yes. What is the particular problem are you having? Posting your current code might help, as it might highlight what is blocking you. But you seem to understand what you need to do from your description, so what's the issue?

Comment: If you are looking for suggestions then if I was to implement such a functionality I would create a class with properties matching the variables from the text file and have some flag like `bool isFileRead`. Then when I want to use some variable then I first will check the flag - if the `isFileRead` is equal to false I'll read the text file and assign the values, otherwise it has been already read and use the class properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO I would recommend a static class for the settings from the File:
This way the file is only read when the class is accessed for the first time.

Hope something like this is suitable for you:

UPDATE:
filled in the read file logic and added the property call

```
public static class Configuration
{
    // public set so you can change the configfile location if necessary
    public static string ConfigurationFile { get; set; }

    // variables from configuration file, private set so they cannot be changed except by changing the configuration and reloading
    public static string Inc_interval { get; private set; }
    public static string Day_Time { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Static constructor - will be called the first time this class is accessed
    /// </summary>
    static Configuration()
    {
        ConfigurationFile = @"C:\somefile";
        ReadConfigFile();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Calling this method will reload the configuration file
    /// </summary>
    public static void Reload()
    {
        ReadConfigFile();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Logic for reading the configuration file
    /// </summary>
    private static void ReadConfigFile()
    {
        // ToDo: Read file here and fill properties
        using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(ConfigurationFile))
        {
            while (!rd.EndOfStream)
            {
                string line = rd.ReadLine();
                if (line.StartsWith("Day_Time:"))
                    Day_Time = line.Remove(0, 9);
                else if (line.StartsWith("Inc_interval:"))
                    interval = line.Remove(0, 13);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Since it's a static class, you can access its properties from all your classes, methods, whatever:

```
timeloop = Configuration.Day_Time;
```

Comment: interesting, that's kinda neat. I have been attempting to learn more about class's and such through the virtual academy but your example above is good. So then I can just call the variables from anywhere at that point right ?

Comment: Yes, since the properties are static, you don't need an object of that class. The first time you actually do something with this class, the static constructor gets called and reads the file. Also, the class is declared as public, so you can call it from all other classes/methods of your project.

Comment: that is excellent, thank you. !! going to make this a bit easier for sure.